# structuredClone( <any object> ) is not an instanceof Object when using Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I need to know if a given variable is an object or not, and for that I used `obj instanceof Object`, which seemed to work well until I made the unit tests using Jest. Then this started evaluating to `false` on seemingly normal objects.

Eventually, I tracked down the issue to the tests themselves, and they were behaving like this:

```js
let obj1 = {
    exampleKey: "exampleValue"
};
let obj2 = structuredClone(obj1);

console.log(obj1 instanceof Object); // true
console.log(obj2 instanceof Object); // false
```

Both evaluated to true on my browser. REPL also evaluated both to true. After a few more tests, I realised that the issue was related to Jest. The above piece of code outputs `true true` before installing Jest and `true false` after installing and running with Jest.

How can I identify if something is an object without running into this issue (by object I mean anything than can be iterated with a `for...in` loop)? Is this behaviour intended or not, why does it happen?

Comment: Same as this: https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/2549

Comment: is there any way to get around that? (for my specific example at least) Apparently its not going to be fixed anytime soon...